# Changing from arrays to nodes in a stack

Tags: java, list, linked-list, stack, nodes

Working on an assignment but i started off doing it wrong, i dont understand nodes very well and need some help chaning my stack code from using arrays to nodes.

Here is my stack code.

```
public class Lstack {
    int size;
    int numUsed = 0;
    Car[] stack;
    public Lstack(){
        stack = new Car[size];
    }
    public void push(Car x){
        stack[numUsed] = x;
        numUsed++;
    }
    public Car pop(){
        Car temp;
        numUsed--;
        temp = stack[numUsed];
        return temp;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        if(numUsed==0){
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    public int size(){
        return numUsed;
    }
    public void display(){
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
        System.out.print("TOP | ");
        for(int i = 0; i < numUsed; i++){
            System.out.print(stack[i].plate +" | ");
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
    }

}
```

And here is my node code

```
public class Node {
    Node next;
    Car name;

    public Node(Node x, Car y){
        next = x;
        name = y;
    }
}
```

How do i change the Lstack class to work with the Node class.

Comment: Try something. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list to understand how a linked list works.

Comment: i understand what a linked list does, im just having a hard time implementing it.

Comment: Take a pen and a paper, and think of everything you must do when adding a new element at the top of the stack, and when removing it, by drawing the existing nodes and the new one, like it's done in the wikipedia page.

Comment: I dont see how this is helping me? I understand whats going on, i just dont know how to put it into my code effectively. I just started working with nodes and they are confusing the hell out of me

Comment: This is how it works here: you try something, get stuck or an error, and then ask a question with the code you tried. We won't do your homework. Try something. If you really understand how a linked list works, you should have no problem. It's just a matter of setting the next pointer of the top node correctly. Drawing nodes on paper really helps reducing the confusion. Try doing it.

Comment: i dont know how to put it here, but i have a car class that has a getter and setter method.

Comment: The Car class is irrelevant to your question. What matters is how you use nodes in your Stack class. A Node contains a Car. It could contain a Truck, or a Bike, or anything else, and the stack would be implemented the same way. I suggest you to re-read the wikipedia article, because based on what you're posting, you do *not* understand how a linked list works.

Answer (score 0):

A Stack is a Linked List in reverse

For a linked list the head node is the `first` node in the collection and each node points to the `next`
node.
For a Stack the head node is the `last` node in the collection and each node points to the 'previous' node.

so for a stack we have

```
 public void push(Node n){
     n.setNextNode(this.head);
     this.head = n;
 }

 public Node pop(){
     Node n = this.head;
     this.head = this.head.getNextNode();
     return n;
 }
```

you will want to add error connection code and make Node generic.